# having clause in sql query returns invalid

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve all the IDs that fit the following criteria:

1. lives on specific street
2. has two telephone numbers
3. has made an order
4. is female

```
select id from Customer 
join Address on Address.customer_id = Customer.id
join Orders on Orders.customer_id = Customer.id
join Gender on Gender.customer_id = Customer.id
join Telephone on Telephone.customer_id = Customer.id
where Address.street_name ='MainStreet' 
and Orders.customer_id is not null
and Gender.gender ='Female'
group by Telephone.customer_id
having count(Telephone.customer_id) = 2
```

When I run this, I receive "Column or expression is not valid" 
When I remove the group by and having, it works fine.

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
select id from Customer 
join Address on Address.customer_id = Customer.id
join Orders on Orders.customer_id = Customer.id
join Gender on Gender.customer_id = Customer.id
join (
select customer_id from Telephone
group by customer_id
having count(customer_id) = 2
) AS Telephone on Telephone.customer_id = Customer.id
where Address.street_name ='MainStreet' 
and Orders.customer_id is not null
and Gender.gender ='Female'
```